# How to retrieve result of an @Async method

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I have a small Spring Boot app waiting for REST calls to start an async job. However what I'd like to do next is get results of those async jobs and store them in DB. But I don't know how to use object returned with Future asynchronically. 
Here is more or less what I have:

```
@RequestMapping("/vlan/{id}/{name}")
public void performVLANConfig(@PathVariable("id") int id, @PathVariable("name") String name) {
    logger.debug("Received req");
    Future<ProcessedRequest> processedRequestFuture= asyncService.processVlan(id, name);

    processedRequestRepository.save(processedRequest);
}
```

But now it just waits for async call to end. Is there any way to let the async method live its life and after it has completed store this completition error?

Comment: Use CompletableFuture with Java 8 or ListenableFuture with earlier versions

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd can you make services return completablefuture? or you need to set the result by calling f.complete(result) yourself? Just curious.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-4.2.html#_web_improvements_2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to attach a callback. If you using `Future` then you can't attach a callback to it, assign to a `ListenableFuture` instead, the service needs to return a `ListenableFuture` of course.

```
ListenableFuture<ProcessedRequest> future = asyncService.processVlan(id, name);

future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<ProcessedRequest>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
          // deal with it
        }
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ProcessedRequest processedRequest) {
            processedRequestRepository.save(processedRequest);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I needed.